# How to access params[] when using a callback on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I'm using the callback `before_update` to call a function on model which set the checkbox value on my variable.

The problem is the checkbox value which is on `params[:mail_checker_issue]` isn't accessible on the model layer.

The question is: How to access this params using the callback `before_update` ? Below my code:

```
module IssueSetChecketIssuePatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
       base.class_eval do
        before_save :before_mail_checker
      end
  end
end

module InstanceMethods
  require_dependency 'issue'
  def before_mail_checker
    self.set_mail_checker_issue(params[:mail_checker_issue]) 
  end

      def set_mail_checker_issue(mail)
      @mail_checker = mail
    end

    def get_mail_checker_issue
      @mail_checker
    end
end 

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  Issue.send(:include, IssueSetChecketIssuePatch)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`params` are a controller concern and are wholly separate from models. Consider what should happen if you tried to save that model from a console, for example.

You need to pass the param to the model after you instantiate it from your controller, then check the value set on the model in your `before_save` callback.

It's also worth noting that your code is somewhat un-Rubyish (and really, looks a lot like Java!) - you could get the same effect by just defining an attr on the model.

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  require_dependency 'issue'
  class Issue
    attr_accessor :mail_checker_issue
  end
end
```

Then, once you have an issue:

```
# Controller code
@issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
@issue.mail_checker_issue = params[:mail_checker_issue]
```

Comment: Haha, you're right. I'm comming from java and I'm noob on ruby yet. Of course I'll take your tips. Thx. Nice code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, models don't know about controllers or params hash.

You should include this logic at your controller instead of forcing it in a callback.

Comment: Are you assuming that's impossible to do it using callbacks?

Comment: Doing it inside a callback is **wrong**. While it's possible with hacks, it's a horrible solution and doesn't make sense given the way code in rails is organized.